# Считается ли цепочка условий за одну команду?

Tags: c#, синтаксис

У меня есть цикл for, который я хочу писать без фигурных скобок (перфекционизм и лень). Будет ли эта цепочка условий работать в цикле, или нет?

```
for(int i = 0; i < mass.count; i++)
    if(a < b) { } else if (a > b) { } else { }
```

Comment: А почему вам кажется, что не будет?

Comment: Будет, конечно. А как, вы думаете, будет выполняться? `if` проверяться каждую итерацию цикла, а `else` выполняться только после него?

Comment: @VladD Хорошо, спасибо

Comment: @VladD А если вместо цикла поставить if? Тоже будет работать? Если во вложённом условии оставить только if, то следующий else будет вложенным или нет?

Comment: if может быть проблема "высящего else" - компилятор не смотрит на форматирование:) Если уж очень сильно хочется без скобочек - выносите тело цикла в отдельную функцию/метод.

Comment: @Minebot: А вот здесь уже возможны принципиальные разночтения, в отличие от `while`. Если я не ошибаюсь, `else` относится к ближайшему `if`, у которого пока нет `else`. Но в случаях вложенных `if`'ов я бы очень рекомендовал фигурные скобки. Потому что это компилятору просто, у него правила прошиты в коде. А человеку легко и ошибиться.

Comment: а вообще, избегайте условий внутри цикла, тернарный оператор альтернатива. https://habrahabr.ru/post/165729/

Comment: @VladD С python получше с этим, там вообще скобок нету) Спасибо за инфу

Comment: @Minebot: Мне не очень понятно, что делают питонисты, когда нужно большой кусок кода заключить в `if` — переформатируют вручную? Со скобками это может сделать IDE. Но по модулю этого в общем-то два стиля, у каждого свои плюсы и минусы.

Comment: оффтопик, но на месте работодателя за такой перфекционизм и лень я бы вас уволил :)

заодно хотелось бы увидеть кусок реальный пример подобной конструкции. Впрочем с пустыми операторами возможно компилятор вообще вырежет этот кусок кода.

Comment: @FonyFazoulyanov и чем же это вам условия внутри циклов не угодили? и что тогда по вашему тернарный оператор, если не условие?

Comment: @teran такой перфекционизьм при нормальном форматировании читается не хуже swich/case конструкций, а форматирование делается в один клик, так что я бы не был столь категоричен

Comment: @rdorn О да. Форматировать 1000 строчек - моё любимое занятие. Форматирование занимает много времени между прочим, поэтому много кода остаётся без форматирования...

Comment: @Minebot ctrl+a, ctrl+x, ctrl+v пишу дольше чем нажимаю

Comment: @Minebot вы попробуйте код не в блокноте писать, тогда с форматирование куда проще будет :)

Comment: @teran Если не уметь пользоваться IDE, то пользы от неё будет столько же, сколько от блокнота

Comment: @Minebot но в целом я не оправдываю корявое форматирование и полностью согласен, что писать нужно сразу нормально

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, считается как одно предложение.

Вы можете представить исходное `if` предложение

```
if(a < b) { } else if (a > b) { } else { }
```

как

```
if(a < b) вложенный-оператор else вложенный-оператор
```

где первым вложенным-оператором является пустой блочный оператор `{}` (пустой блок), а вторым вложенным оператором является в свою очередь `if` оператор `if (a > b) { } else { }`

Как написано в книге "Язык программирования C#" с участием в качестве автора Андерса Хейлсберга (Глава 8. Операторы)

> "Вложенный оператор можно использовать **внутри** других операторов,
>   причем степень вложенности не ограничена."

Возможно в спецификации языка есть некоторые ограничения на вложенность, тем не менее они не существенны для реальных программ.

Comment: говорят на ms vc++ был баг с вложенностью больше 127 уровней.

Comment: да, это правда:)

Comment: о боже! Я не переживу что мои 128 вложенных циклов нельзя написать одним куском ... кода =)

Comment: @KoVadim а если серьезно, это реально проблема или просто маньяки проверяли компилятор на прочность?

Comment: Это тогда получается, что сильно говнокодить нельзя :)

Comment: @rdorn нет, это просто обычные программисты, но особые. Им так было удобно (на самом деле они не знали о том, что условия можно писать через && и ||),

Comment: @KoVadim Сейчас в C# 6 введена конструкция, которая позволяет заменить предложение if ( obj != null && obj.method() ) { /*...*/ } на if ( obj?.method() ) { /*...*/ }